# Center form with display:table-cell

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a submit button inside a form-tag. This form tag has some css-propertys:

1. On Desktop it has a fixed with
2. On mobile devices it has a percentage-width

The problem is, that the submit button inside the form has width:auto; and margin:0 auto; so that it´s centered inside the form-tag. But webkit (mobile safari and safari) doesn´t understand that. In those browser the submit button is not centered but on the left side. So I wrote a jquery script which calculates the width and sets it to the submit button (instead of width:auto). That was the fix.

I made a research and now I know, that I could use display:table-cell; in the form tag, which will center the content (the submit button) BUT: that means that I can not center the form itself.
So my question is, how to modify the code below so that the form is centered inside the wrapper and the submit button inside the form?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#wrap{
    width:1000px;
    background:red; 
}
form {
    height:100px;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    -webkit-box-align: center;    
}
form input[type=submit], form input[type="button"], form input[type="reset"], form button {
    width:auto;
    min-width:40%;
    height:32px;
    margin:20px auto;
    line-height:14px;
    padding:9px 15px;
    background-color:#617798;
    border:0;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    /* Border-Radius */
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius:5px;
    -o-border-radius:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline;
    /* iPad-Button-Reset:*/
    -webkit-appearance:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<h1>Titel Blafasel</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `display:table-cell;` inside form {} it should work.

Comment: Yes it will work, but if you replace the text-align:center; in the form-css it will not work. I forgot to replace this in the example, because I don´t want to center all text in the form tag, just the submit button

Comment: @julesdude - change display: inline to display: block inside form input[type=submit], form input[type="button"], form input[type="reset"], form button {}

Comment: @julesdude - You can later make text-align:center; to text-align:left; or remove it

Comment: Thanks, you´r right. I see only one problem left: fill in a input type file before the input type submit and try to horizontally align the input. You will have no success:
form input[type=file]:not(.reset){
 display:block;
 margin:0 auto;
} Do you know how to center a input type file within this code?

Comment: @julesdude - Just increase form width to fit in both fields.